# Drop/Create Triggers in a Transaction Question - Will the trigger run after

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-trigger

I would like to inquire about the behavior of a trigger (let's say "after update" trigger) that is dropped at the beginning of a transaction and then re-created at the end of a transaction,- specifically, will the trigger run during the commit phase of the transaction (assuming that in the middle of the transaction I executed some scripts that would normally trigger the trigger)?

Consider this example.

1. Start Transaction
2. Drop trigger
3. Run scripts that make changes to the table that would normally trigger the (dropped) trigger
4. Re-create the (dropped) trigger
5. Commit Transaction

At line #5, when database commits entire transaction, will the re-created trigger run or not?

**UPDATE**

I would like to re-phrase the question if this is not possible/or good idea to do it this way. Instead of dropping/re-creating, I believe a better solution is to disable/enable the trigger. In this, when the trigger is enabled, will it run at the end of the transaction?

**UPDATE 2**

As suggested by everyone, for my scenario do this:

Start TX
 disable trig, run SQL, enable  trig
Commit TX

The trigger will not fire which is what I want.

Comment: There is an easy way to answer that yourself - and that is to give it a try :)

Comment: This has [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) all over it.

Comment: If you had even attempted to try this you would find out that you can't create a trigger inside of a transaction as it must be the only statement in the batch.

Comment: OK then, what about instead of dropping/re-creating a trigger I disable the trigger and then at the end of tx I enable the trigger.

Comment: Did you try it? But why do you need to disable a trigger like this? The point of a trigger is to capture the event. Disabling it rather defeats the point of having the trigger in the first place. But seriously, you should at least attempt to try this out first.

Comment: We have an update application that performs db updates when user updates from one version to another version of our product. While the update application performs db changes, we don't want the triggers to trigger.

Comment: You can disable a trigger at the start of your transaction and then enable it again at the end without dropping it.

Comment: just DISABLE/ENABLE...ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] DISABLE TRIGGER [trg_trgname]

Comment: No, I don't want to run the trigger, period. That's why I asked the question if the re-enabled/or re-created trigger will run at the end.

Comment: I messed up the comment, I meant to say the SQL to enable the trigger, not to run the trigger itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger will not run if you ENABLE the trigger between the DML statement and the COMMIT;  For example, this will not cause the trigger to execute:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] DISABLE TRIGGER [trg_trgtest]

UPDATE [dbo].[myTable]
SET [language] = 'fr'
WHERE id = 6

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] ENABLE TRIGGER [trg_trgtest]

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a trigger places an exclusive metadata lock (Sch-M) on the table, preventing any queries or DML, which all require a Schema Stability Lock (Sch-S), for the duration of the transaction.

EG

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists foo
go
create table foo(id int primary key)

go
create trigger tg_foo on foo after insert
as
begin
  select 'tg_foo trigger running' msg
end

go

begin transaction
go
drop trigger tg_foo 
go
select o.name, o.type_desc, request_mode
from sys.dm_tran_locks tl
join sys.objects o
  on o.object_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
where request_session_id = @@spid 
and o.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

optputs

```
name                type_desc   request_mode
------------------- ----------- --------------
foo                 USER_TABLE  Sch-M

(1 row affected)
```

So when you drop a trigger at the beginning of a transaction, all access to that table will be blocked until you commit or rollback the transaction.

And so

> will the trigger run during the commit phase of the transaction
>   (assuming that in the middle of the transaction I executed some
>   scripts that would normally trigger the trigger)?

So on commit, the script that would normally "trigger the trigger" will become unblocked, and run, triggering the trigger as normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable a trigger, then execute and commit a transaction, then re-enable the trigger, the trigger will not "run" for the already completed transaction.

Comment: I knew that, but in our case the Update application requires to execute SQL to re-enable the trigger as the last statement before committing the transaction.

Comment: The answers states to re-enable the trigger as the last action in the transaction?

Comment: @ActiveX smoore4 shows exactly how to do this, but digital.aaron is saying the same thing and said it first.

Comment: digital aaro said: to do it after commit, where as smoore4 solution is to do it as the last line before commit <== this will work for me. Thanks. Looks like dropping a trigger for what I want to do is wrong tool for the job, what I want is to use disable/enable